# Servlet controller - Redirect with parameters

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I'm using Spring MVC web app: Servlet + JSP + Hibernate. This is a part from my `CustomerController.java`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/CustomerList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView customerList() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("Customer.List"); // for Tiles View
    model.addObject("listCustomer", DAO_Customer.getListCustomer());
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/Customer/{id}/Delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    boolean isSuccess = DAO_Customer.deleteCustomer(id);
    if (!isSuccess) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Failed");
    }
    model.addAttribute("success", "Successed");

    return "redirect:/CustomerList";
}
```

and here is the code in `CustomerList.jsp` file to display:

```
...
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <p>${error}</p>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty success}">
    <p>${success}</p>
</c:if>
...
```

I want to redirect to `/CustomerList` and include parameters `error` + `success`. 

The problem is, when I run, it return `/CustomerList?success=Successed` and nothing show up expect the default customer list


I search a lot but really don't know how to do what I want. Thanks everyone for read and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [RedirectAttributes#addAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html).

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Customer/{id}/Delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") int id, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  boolean isSuccess = DAO_Customer.deleteCustomer(id);
  if (!isSuccess) {
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("error", "Failed");
  } else{ //also required
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("success", "Successed");
  }
  return "redirect:/CustomerList";
}
```

In this case, the url will turn into `/CustomerList?success=Successed` if successful.

And you can access param value with `EL` as follows:

```
${param.success} or ${param.error}
```

---

Also you can use `RedirectAttributes#addFlashAttribute`.

```
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Successed");
```

Then you can access directly as `${success}` or `${error}`.

Comment: Awesome ! It worked so perfect with me ! Thanks you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

Much too late, but if someone is still wondering about this - the easiest solution is to use redirect and add attribute to session:

In Servlet:

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("<your attribute>");
```

In Servlet to which you are redirecting:

```
private void checkMessages(HttpServletRequest request) {
    SomeObject result = (SomeObject) request.getSession().getAttribute("<your attribute>");
    if (result != null) {
        request.setAttribute(result);
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("<your attribute>");
    }
}
```

Works like a charm!